# Push notification CallBack is not working PhoneGap iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am trying to implmenet push notification in iPhone-Phonegap.
I am sucessfully getting the device token in 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method but when i an trying to pass this token to phonegap js ,nothing is working. i am getting any return value in that PushNotification.js.
I am following the following source code
https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-phonegap-plugin

Please let me know if i am missing something.
Thanks in Advance.